# Define operators on DataGridViewCell

Tags: c#, oop, datagridview

I need to define some custom operators on DataGridView cells, and try to follow the OOP perspective.

I derived a new class from the standard *DataGridViewTextBoxCell* (call it DataGridViewTextBoxCell_1 for the sake of this question) as follows

```
class DataGridViewTextBoxCell_1:DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
  public static bool operator >=(DataGridViewTextBoxCell_1 a, DataGridViewTextBoxCell_1 b)
    { // do something }
}
```

Thus **>=** is the new operator defined on text box cells.
Now, when I create a datagridview control named *Datagrid_1* and add new cells with cell template set us *DataGridViewTextBoxCell_1*, namely

```
 this.Datagrid_1.Columns[this.Datagrid_1.Columns.Count - 1].CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell_1();
```

I cannot use the above defined operator **>=** on cells of DataGrid_1, although their template supports the operatons ( I'm getting an error that Operator >= cannot be applied to operands of type 'DataGridViewCell' ).

I assume that I can use *casting*, but for extensive use that might be inefficient.

On the other hand, I'm not sure how to extend the DataGridViewCell class ( to which the error refers to) and make the DataGridView Control to use that new extended Cell class, as the relation between DataGridViewCell and DataGridView classes is not entirely clear.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on this matter.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. However, I am guessing that since the operator “>=” method is returning a `bool` … that would indicate that the “grid cell” is of type `bool.` Which translates to a simple `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell.` It is unclear why there is a need for a “custom” “Cell type”?

Comment: In addition, it appears the code is attempting to “compare” two cells in the grid and place the result of that comparison in another cell. There are many ways to achieve this without having to create “custom” cells for the grid. I recommend looking at a `DataTable` which would achieve what you describe easily without having to create any custom cells.

Comment: @JohnG, the operator >= indeed returns a bool, however there is no reason for the grid cell to be a bool (it can very well contain datetime, or a numeric data). As for your second comment on putting the comparison result in the other cell, the code doesn't want to do that, and I'm not sure which part makes you think that. All I'm looking for is to have a way to compare values of different cells in a neat way ( >= being a single example) . I can feed the cell values to functions of course, but doing it in OOP fashion will make the overall code cleaner.

Comment: Creating a method to compare two cells in a grid is trivial. As you state the comparison could return any value, however since the “operator” method IS returning “some” value, I assumed the result would be stored somewhere. It is unclear how the “custom” cell is used. In other words, the posted code “extends” from the `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` … but why? What is this “extended” cell going to contain?

Comment: @JohnG, it is clearly stated in the 1st line of my comment above that the operator >= returns bool, not any value. My question is not about creating a method to compare 2 cells in the grid. Suppose I loop over the rows of the grid, and apply the comparison operators on the cells (or whatever the operator at the moment is). If the cells are a and b I can have a method F doing the job of the operator >= with the call F(a,b), however, if the grid supports >= directly, I can just use a>=b  which is syntactically nicer ( there can be many more examples). This is the point of extension.

Comment: I am not sure where you got the idea that the `DataGridView` “Cells” support the operation… “CellA >= CellB” directly. I have never seen this done on a cell to cell comparison, usually you have to get the “cells” `Value` if you want to compare them. I could possibly see this on its “default” cells, however, I can assure you that its not going to support this “directly” using a “custom” cell. I am guessing I am missing something in this question, I will bow out.

Comment: I am not trying to dissuade you from “extending” the `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` as you describe, however, it seems like a lot of unnecessary work and I do not think this is going to be a trivial thing to do, however I support your effort. As I recommended earlier, a am confident that using a `DataTable` for this will be much easier as it is “designed” for this kind of thing. Pick your poison… good luck.